# Unable to throw exception on ajax call from controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want throw exception on client side on ajax call but I have no status code.
what I do to handle error on ajax error function.

When I call ajax function it generate some exception on SaveAccount Controller and I handle it through HandleExceptionAttribute and I return json at last but it hit on success function insted of error what is the problem. 
please help. Thanks

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    filterContext.Exception.Message,
                }
            };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
}

[HandleExceptionAttribute]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAccount(AccountViewModel vm)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new AdvisorFinancialEntities())
            {
                ..........
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception e = new Exception("Failed to save account");
            e.Data.Add("Accounts", "SaveAccount");

            throw e;
        }
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

```html
 $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveAccount", "Accounts")',
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (result) {
                    ShowToastMessage("Account has been saved successfully", "Success",true);      
                    Reset();
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    ShowToastMessage(err.Message, "Save Account",false);      

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;` the server understands that you already handled the exception and that's why it returns 200 as status.

You can add `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;` after `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;` and it should return 500 as status code of your AJAX call.